# How to improve randomForest performance?

Tags: r, performance, random-forest

I have a training set of size 38 MB (12 attributes with 420000 rows). I am running the below `R` snippet, to train the model using `randomForest`. This is taking hours for me.

```
rf.model <- randomForest(
              Weekly_Sales~.,
              data=newdata,
              keep.forest=TRUE,
              importance=TRUE,
              ntree=200,
              do.trace=TRUE,
              na.action=na.roughfix
            )
```

I think, due to `na.roughfix`, it is taking long time to execute. There are so many `NA's` in the training set.

Could someone let me know how can I improve the performance?

My system configuration is:

```
Intel(R) Core i7 CPU @ 2.90 GHz
RAM - 8 GB
HDD - 500 GB
64 bit OS
```

Comment: Crucially you didn't tell us F, the number of features, or the number of columns in your data; see below for why the effect of F is quadratic. (But it looks like Kaggle Walmart Store Sales dataset. In that data, *train.csv* has only *Store, Dept, IsHoliday* but *features.csv* adds 10 features, most of which were useless. Adding in your own user-generated features, F could be anything from 4 to 50+... like I keep hammering home, it makes an enormous difference. Aggressively figure out what the low-importance features are and exclude them, at least for exploration, not final model generation.)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

(The tl;dr is you should a) increase nodesize to >> 1 and b) exclude very low-importance feature columns, maybe even exclude (say) 80% of your columns. Your issue is almost surely not `na.roughfix`, but if you suspect that, run `na.roughfix` separately as a standalone step, before calling `randomForest`. Get that red herring out of the way at first.)

Now, all of the following advice only applies until you blow out your memory limits, so measure your memory usage, and make sure you're not exceeding. (Start with ridiculously small parameters, then scale them up, measure the runtime, and keep checking it didn't increase disproportionately.)

The main parameters affecting the performance of randomForest are:

- **mtry** (less is faster)
- **ntrees**
- **number of features**/cols in data - more is quadratically slower, or worse! See below
- **number of observations/rows** in data
- ncores (more is faster - as long as parallel option is being used)
- some performance boost by setting importance=F and proximity=F (don't compute proximity matrix)
- **Never ever use the insane default `nodesize=1`**, for classification! In Breiman's package, you can't directly set maxdepth, but use `nodesize` as a proxy for that, and also read all the good advice at: [CrossValidated: "Practical questions on tuning Random Forests"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/practical-questions-on-tuning-random-forests)
- So here your data has 4.2e+5 rows, then if each node shouldn't be smaller than ~0.1%, try `nodesize=42`. (First try nodesize=420 (1%), see how fast it is, then rerun, adjusting nodesize down. Empirically determine a good nodesize for this dataset.)
- runtime is proportional to ~ 2^D_max, i.e. polynomial to (-log1p(nodesize))
- optionally you can also speedup by using sampling, see `strata,sampsize` arguments

Then a first-order estimate of runtime, denoting mtry=M, ntrees=T, ncores=C, nfeatures=F, nrows=R, maxdepth=D_max, is:

```
Runtime proportional to: T * F^2 * (R^1.something) * 2^D_max / C
```

(Again, all bets are off if you exceed memory. Also, try running on only one core, then 2, then 4 and verify you actually do get linear speedup. And not slowdown.)
(The effect of large R is worse than linear, maybe quadratic, since tree-partitioning has to consider all partitions of the data rows; certainly it's somewhat worse than linear. Check that by using sampling or indexing to only give it say 10% of rows).

***Tip: keeping lots of crap low-importance features quadratically increases runtime, for a sublinear increase in accuracy. This is because at each node, we must consider all possible feature selection (or whatever number mtry) allows. And within each tree, we must consider all (F-choose-mtry) possible combinations of features.***
So here's my methodology, doing "fast-and-dirty feature-selection for performance":

1. generate a tree normally (slow), although use a sane `nodesize=42` or larger
2. look at rf$importances or `randomForest::varImpPlot()`. Pick only the top-K features, where you choose K; for a silly-fast example, choose K=3. Save that entire list for future reference.
3. now rerun the tree but only give it `newdata[,importantCols]`
4. confirm that speed is quadratically faster, and oob.error is not much worse
5. once you know your variable importances, you can turn off `importance=F`
6. tweak mtry and nodesize (tweak one at a time), rerun and measure speed improvement
7. plot your performance results on logarithmic axes
8. post us the results! Did you corroborate the above? Any comments on memory usage?

(Note that the above is not a statistically valid procedure for actual feature-selection, do not rely on it for that, read randomForest package for the actual proper methods for RF-based feature-selection.)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect  do.trace  might also consume time... instead do.trace = TRUE, you can used do.trace = 5 (to show only 5 traces) just to have some feel about errors. For large dataset, do.trace would take up a lot time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another think I noticed:
the correct is `ntrees`, not `ntree`.
The default is `500` for the `randomForest` package.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to actually use more recent packages that are purpose-built for highly dimensional / high volume data sets. They run their code using lower-level languages (C++ and/or Java) and in certain cases use parallelization.

I'd recommend taking a look into these three:

ranger (uses C++ compiler)
randomForestSRC (uses C++ compiler)
h2o (Java compiler - needs Java version 8 or higher)
Also, some additional reading here to give you more to go off on which package to choose: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04409.pdf

Page 8 shows benchmarks showing the performance improvement of ranger against randomForest against growing data size - ranger is WAY faster due to linear growth in runtime rather than non-linear for randomForest for rising tree/sample/split/feature sizes.

Good Luck!