# Error: protect(): protection stack overflow

Tags: r

i got an error while i am running a big data. Error has explained by the following sample sample

Load data

```
   mdata <- as.matrix(read.table('https://gubox.box.com/shared/static/qh4spcxe2ba5ymzjs0ynh8n8s08af7m0.txt', header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, sep = '\t'))
```

Install and load library

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") 
biocLite("impute") 
library(impute)
```

Sets a limit on the number of nested expressions

```
options(expressions = 500000)
```

Apply k-nearest neighbors for missing value imputation

```
res <-impute.knn(mdata)
```

and I got:

> Error: protect(): protection stack overflow

If anybody has solution or suggestion, please share. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to start R like this: `R --max-ppsize 500000`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826906/how-to-solve-protection-stack-overflow-issue-in-r-studio?rq=1)

Comment: Yes i did it . but no hope .

Comment: Got the same issue, here. Using rtsne after caret, data.table, etc. Did you solve your issue in the end?

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem, i tried to use the data block by block . You can look at the [post](https://www.biostars.org/p/182027/#182330).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Links to answers are considered bad practice, can you edit your answer to include the relevant code with a brief explanation? (looks like you could even just copy your other answer here)