# Error resolution for R Error, "Error: protect(): protection stack overflow"?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to run a LASSO model in RStudio on proteomics data. We have data from 3000 proteins, and I am trying to load all proteins with our outcome into a formula as below:

```
mod.spec_adj <- as.formula(paste(sprintf("%s ~ %s","outcome",
                                         paste(sprintf("`%s`",var.list),collapse=" + " ))))
```

Where `var.list` is the list of proteins. This formula is then used as the formula for a LASSO using the caret package. However, when I do this R throws the error `Error: protect(): protection stack overflow`

Importantly, I have searched on this forum before and followed the directions in [this post: How to solve 'protection stack overflow' issue in R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826906/how-to-solve-protection-stack-overflow-issue-in-r-studio).

Specifically, I have used the terminal to open a new rstudio session:
`C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin>rstudio.exe --max-ppsize=5000000`

This opens a new rstudio session and, interestingly, the code runs to completion and the formula object is (at least as far as I can tell) loaded with the correct formula. But it still throws the "protection stack overflow" error whenever I get to that line of code. Even though everything seems 'correct' to me, the fact that it is still throwing the error concerns me and I would like to find a way to have the code run without error.

Is there a way to get around this error? Did I start RStudio with the incorrect command? Is there a way to build the formula piecewise (e.g. 100 proteins at a time instead of 3000 all at once) so that the as.formula line doesn't cause an issue with the protection stack? Any help would be appreciated.