# R: any random forest packages in which the maximum depth of trees can be controlled?

Tags: r, random-forest

The particular problem I try to solve require me to control the depth of trees in a random forest model. The most popular randomForest package does not allow users to precisely control the maximum depth. Are there any random forest implementations that control the max depth?

I am dealing with a large dataset, so speed is also a consideration.

Comment: If you aren't tied to a particular tree-based method then XgBoost is a gradient boosting implementation that allows control of the maximum depth.

Answer (score 1):

Random forest creates deep trees (its kind of its thing in comparison to XGBoost and others). So, why do you want to use random forest with a set depth? See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/how-to-tune-the-depth-and-min-samples-leaf-of-random-forest-with-correlated) for why setting maximum depth for random forest is a bad idea.

Also, as discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075506/how-to-improve-randomforest-performance), node size can be used as a practical proxy to control the maximum depth that each tree grows to. That link also contains some comments about improving performance.

Comment: The reason I want to limit depth is because I only want to look at the 2 way (or n-way) partition. The goal here is not more predictive power.

Comment: Then you don't want random forest. Look into hierarchical clustering or recursive partitioning trees.